# Indefinite summation of multiplication of two Bessel functions

Tags: bessel-functions

Could anyone give an insight on how to prove the following formula?

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}J_{n}(\alpha)J_{N+n}(\alpha)=\delta_{N0} \, ,$$

where $N$ is an integer. I checked many references but failed to figure out the calculation method. By the way, I found this relation during some numerical calculations about Bessel functions.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. Did you mean $\delta_{N,0}$?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. What I mean is that the value equals to 1 when $N = 0$, and equals to 0 in other cases. I have got the answer from Francois. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case $y+z=0$ of the [addition formula](https://archive.org/stream/treatiseontheory00watsuoft#page/30/mode/1up) $J_N(y+z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbf Z}J_n(y)J_{N-n}(z)$, plus the fact that $J_k(z)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(k\theta-z\sin\theta)\,d\theta=J_{-k}(-z)$.